# What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, slice

I see at many places the use of slice assignment for `list`s. I am able to understand its use when used with (non-default) indices, but I am not able to understand its use like:

```
a_list[:] = ['foo', 'bar']
```

How is that different from

```
a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Creates a new `list` in memory and points the name `a_list` at it. It is irrelevant what `a_list` pointed at before.

```
a_list[:] = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Calls the [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) method of the `a_list` object with a [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) as the index, and a new `list` created in memory as the value.

`__setitem__` evaluates the `slice` to figure out what indexes it represents, and calls `iter` on the value it was passed. It then iterates over the object, setting each index within the range specified by the `slice` to the next value from the object. For `list`s, if the range specified by the `slice` is not the same length as the iterable, the `list` is resized. This allows you to do a number of interesting things, like delete sections of a list:

```
a_list[:] = [] # deletes all the items in the list, equivalent to 'del a_list[:]'
```

or inserting new values in the middle of a list:

```
a_list[1:1] = [1, 2, 3] # inserts the new values at index 1 in the list
```

However, with "extended slices", where the `step` is not one, the iterable must be the correct length:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst[::2] = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 2
```

The main things that are different about slice assignment to `a_list` are:

1. `a_list` must already point to an object
2. That object is modified, instead of pointing `a_list` at a new object
3. That object must support `__setitem__` with a `slice` index
4. The object on the right must support iteration
5. No name is pointed at the object on the right. If there are no other references to it (such as when it is a literal as in your example), it will be reference counted out of existence after the iteration is complete.

Comment: I read this in the docs(http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Just the default index was my doubt :)

Comment: "For lists, if the range specified by the slice is not the same length as the iterable, the list is resized." This is true only if the step value of the range is 1.  For step values other than 1, the assigned iterable must yield the correct number of items.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. I tacked that on at the end because I forgot to mention it and I knew there was some situation where it had to be the same length.

Answer (score 16):

The difference is quite huge! In

```
a_list[:] = ['foo', 'bar']
```

You modify a existing list that was bound to the name `a_list`. On the other hand,

```
a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

assigns a new list to the name `a_list`.

Maybe this will help:

```
a = a_list = ['foo', 'bar'] # another name for the same list
a_list = ['x', 'y'] # reassigns the name a_list
print a # still the original list

a = a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
a_list[:] = ['x', 'y'] # changes the existing list bound to a
print a # a changed too since you changed the object
```

Answer (score 3):

By assigning to `a_list[:]`, `a_list` still reference to the same list object, with contents modified. By assigning to `a_list`, `a_list` now reference to a new list object.

Check out its `id`:

```
>>> a_list = []
>>> id(a_list)
32092040
>>> a_list[:] = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> id(a_list)
32092040
>>> a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> id(a_list)
35465096
```

As you can see,  its `id` doens't change with the slice assignment version.

---

The different between the two could result quite different result, for instance, when the list is a parameter of function:

```
def foo(a_list):
    a_list[:] = ['foo', 'bar']

a = ['original']
foo(a)
print(a)
```

With this, `a` is modified as well, but if  `a_list = ['foo', 'bar']` were used instead, `a` remains its original value.

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = ['foo', 'bar']
a=a_list[:]  # by this you get an exact copy of a_list 
print(a)
a=[1,2,3] # even if you modify a it will not affect a_list
print(a)
print(a_list)
```

Comment: The question was asking about assigning `['foo', 'bar']` to `a_list[:]`.