# Behavior of colon operator in x = myList[:] vs myList[:] = x

Tags: python, list-comprehension, slice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d)

I don't have money for school so I am teaching myself some Python whilst working shifts at a tollbooth on the highway (long nights with few customers). (BTW: Coursera should be translated to all languages...)

I have read here that if I have a list `l`:

```
l = ['a', '', 'b']
```

and I want to filter out empty strings like so:

```
l = [c for c in l if c]
```

or like so:

```
l = filter(lambda x: x, l)
```

it is advisable to do this instead:

```
l[:] = ... # either method 1 or method 2 above
```

not to "lose" the reference to the first `l`, especially in case other variables were pointing to it.

My question:

- Why is it that `l[:]` denotes "the contents of `l`" in this case, allowing specifically reassignment to the "same" `l`, when elsewhere I think of it as a "same size slice", conveniently *creating a copy* of l for me?
- Did I *misunderstand* how to use the `l[:]` for same-list-reassignments completely?

I thought that if I had an `l` and I asked for a `l[:]`, the latter was an actual copy of the original `l`?

Reference: "Learning Python" -> *There are a variety of
ways to copy a list, including using the built-in list function and the standard library
copy module. Perhaps the most common way is to slice from start to finish*

Thanks!

Comment: not quite. This is asking basically what the difference is between l[:] and l[:] = ..., as far as I understand it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I think this is probably far enough from that question to be considered a useful standalone question

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really don't think this question is an exact duplicate. Maybe it could be worded to show emphasis on the difference between x = l[:] and l[:] = x, but this is definitely a different question. You can test that by looking at the answers to the other question and noticing that none of them would adequately answer this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference in Python between getting a slice of a list and setting a slice of a list. Indeed, they are actually separate operations (`__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, respectively). So, what's true for the get case may not be true for set.

In the former case, `l[:]` means to get a copy of the list (it generates a brand new list which has all the same contents as the old list). In the latter case, `l[:] = ...` means to set the contents of the list to something else.

Comment: "indeed they are actually separate operations (`__getitem__` and `__setitem__` ...)  Very nice (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Because a LHS slice operator basically says *enumerate through this list and assign something to each index*, while a RHS operator says *enumerate through this list, and create a new object with the values*.

So lets see it in action:

### LHS

```
l[:] = [c for c in l if c!=0]  #ignore how stupid this list comprehension is
```

basically gets broken down into:

```
l[0] = l[0] if l[0] != 0
l[1] = l[1] if l[1] != 0
...
l[n] = l[n] if l[n] != 0
```

So because you're enumerating through it and assigning values, you're not creating any new objects -- just giving new values to the indices of l.

But, on the other hand, doing

```
l = anything
```

Changes the reference that the variable `l` holds. After that, it points to a totally different object in memory.

### RHS

Now,

```
c = l[:]
```

will give you a copy of `l`, not a reference to `l`. This has to be true, because otherwise,

```
c = l[1:5]
```

would have to change the value of `l` if it were to try and use the same object reference as `l`.

Comment: +1 "This has to be true, because otherwise..." :-)

Answer (score 2):

When using a slice operator on the left-hand side of an assignment, you are telling python to store the sequence on the right-hand side in the selected elements of the list.

In other words, you are not replacing `l`, you are assigning to the elements *within* `l`.

Comment: +1 Did not know about the slice operator on the left-side