# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset train with more than 16k observation.I have a variable fare_amount and i want to filter out all the negative values that are present in the variable.

- fare_amount
  0         4.5
  1        16.9
  2         5.7
  3         7.7
  4         5.3
  5        12.1
  6         7.5
  7        16.5
  9         8.9
  10        0
  11        5.5
  12        4.1
  13        7.0
  .           .
  .           .
  16065

````
train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
train = train.drop(train[train.isnull().any(1)].index, axis = 0)
from collections import Counter
Counter(int(train['fare_amount'])<0)
```TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

want to remove all the values that are less than 0
keep getting an error
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
````

Comment: You need to look at your data and inspect its various types when you see an error like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the Counter class works, but I believe the following should work for removing negative numbers from the fare_amount list:

```
tempList = [item for item in fare_amount if item >= 0]
fare_amount = tempList
```

- See more: [Python: Removing negatives from a list of numbers (answered January 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959964/python-removing-negatives-from-a-list-of-numbers)

Comment: Ran it again getting an error saying variable fare_amount is not defined.If you show me in a code that will be very helpful.