# Python list slicing

Tags: python, slice

I learned that list slicing returns a new list instance.
So I think this code wouldn't work, since  b[:] is different to b instance. However, the result is 5, and it means list second copied list first. I'm confused about slicing. Doesn't it return a new instance?

```
def copy(a,b):
        b[:] = a[:]

first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
second = []
copy(first,second)
print second[-1]
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d

Comment: By doing `b[:] = something` you are *updating* the list object `b` references. This works because lists are mutable. So in your function, the (empty) list object created assigned to `second` is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **slice assignment** here:

```
b[:] = a[:]
```

Contents of `b` from start to end is **replacing** with contents of a.