# How can I randomly populate an array from another array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
rand_arr=[0, ]
def rand_key_gen(arr):
    for x in range(0, 25):
        rand_arr[x] = random.choice(arr)
```

This is incomplete. But the problem here is that I might get the same value again. How do I circumvent this situation?

Comment: So to clarify, you want each item from `arr` to appear once in `rand_arr`? (also for the record in Python they're called lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.shuffle` to achieve a shuffled list from the original list. But as it mutate the original list, make a copy of original list first.

```
import random
shuffled_lst=lst[:]
random.shuffle(shuffled_lst)
print "Reshuffled list : ", shuffled_lst
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). It will select the required number of non-repeating elements from `arr`:

```
import random
rand_arr = [0]
def rand_key_gen(arr):
    rand_arr[:] = random.sample(arr, 25)
```

There's no need for the loop, since you can modify `rand_arr` via [slice assigment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10155951/2301450).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `random.shuffle`:

```
from random import shuffle

new_list = old_list[:]  # copy
shuffle(new_list)
print(new_list)
```

If you want a smaller list, you can use slicing.