# Remove a nested list if any of multiple values is found

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list of lists and I'd like to remove all nested lists which contain any of multiple values.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
indices = [i for i,val in enumerate(list_of_lists) if (1,6) in val]

print(indices)
[0]
```

I'd like a lists of indices where this conditions is so that I can:

```
del list_of_lists[indices]
```

To remove all nested lists which contain certain values. I'm guessing the problem is where I try to check against multiple values `(1,6)` as using either `1` or `6` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a set operation:

```
if not {1, 6}.isdisjoint(val)
```

A set is disjoint if none of the values appear in the other sequence or set:

```
>>> {1, 6}.isdisjoint([1, 2])
False
>>> {1, 6}.isdisjoint([3, 4])
True
```

Or just test both values:

```
if 1 in val or 6 in val
```

I'd not build a list of indices. Just rebuild the list and filter *out* anything you don't want in the new list:

```
list_of_lists[:] = [val for val in list_of_lists if {1, 6}.isdisjoint(val)]
```

By assigning to the `[:]` whole slice you replace all indices in `list_of_lists`, updating the list object *in-place*:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> another_ref = list_of_lists
>>> list_of_lists[:] = [val for val in list_of_lists if {1, 6}.isdisjoint(val)]
>>> list_of_lists
[[3, 4]]
>>> another_ref
[[3, 4]]
```

See [What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d) for more detail on what assigning to a slice does.

Comment: Wow, that's great. I didn't know about assigning to slices. In case anybody else wants to read more about it- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10155987/2694260

Comment: @Bprodz: ah, that's indeed a nice reference to use. :-)