# Python: Pass by reference and slice assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function, reference

In Python, lists are passed by reference to functions, right?

If that is so, what's happening here?

```
>>> def f(a):
...     print(a)
...     a = a[:2]
...     print(a)
...
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> f(b)
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: `a[:] = a[:2]` is what you should be doing.

Comment: Or `del a[2:]` would work as well, and be more readable.

Comment: `f` receives a reference to the list, not to the `b` variable; assigning to `a` will not affect the `b` variable. While `f` is passed a reference, "pass by reference" has a specific meaning that does not apply to Python's parameter passing model.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is the best reference I've seen for learning about how this part of Python works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the objects are passed by reference but `a = a[:2]` basically creates a new local variable that points to slice of the list.

To modify the list object in place you can assign it to its slice(slice assignment).

Consider `a` and `b` here equivalent to your global `b` and local `a`, here assigning `a` to new object doesn't affect `b`:

```
>>> a = b = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> a = a[:2]  # The identifier `a` now points to a new object, nothing changes for `b`.
>>> a, b
([1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4370921480, 4369473992)  # `a` now points to a different object
```

Slice assignment work as expected:

```
>>> a = b = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> a[:] = a[:2]  # Updates the object in-place, hence affects all references.
>>> a, b
([1, 2], [1, 2])
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4370940488, 4370940488)  # Both still point to the same object
```

---

Related: [What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d)

Answer (score 6):

In the statement:

```
a = a[:2]
```

you are creating a *new local (to `f()`) variable* which you call using the same name as the input argument `a`.

That is, what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
def f(a):
    print(a)
    b = a[:2]
    print(b)
```

Instead, you should be changing `a` *in place* such as:

```
def f(a):
    print(a)
    a[:] = a[:2]
    print(a)
```

Comment: Nitpick: You are not creating a new local variable / overshadowing an input argument. Arguments are local variables. You are just reusing the same name.

Comment: @Artyer You are right. I was kind of careless with terminology here. Edit will follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When you do:

```
a = a[:2]
```

it reassigns `a` to a new value (The first two items of the list).

All Python arguments are passed by reference. You need to change the object that it is refered to, instead of making `a` refer to a new object.

```
a[2:] = []
# or
del a[2:]
# or
a[:] = a[:2]
```

Where the first and last assign to slices of the list, changing the list in-place (affecting its value), and the middle one also changes the value of the list, by deleting the rest of the elements.

Comment: array slices are not passed by reference.

Comment: @DavidBandel If you are talking about something like `f(a[:2])`, that passes the result of evaluating `a[:2]` "by reference" to f. On lists, this creates a copy of some part of the list, but that is beside the point (that Python has no "pass-by-value" semantics). For example, `f(x := a[:2]); x[0] is a[0]` could be False for a list.

Comment: How can you even regard something as having been passed by reference if you are never again able to access the thing our "reference" is a pointer to? I'd regard it as a grey area in the value/reference dichotomy.