# what is r[:] = [r, r, None] for

Tags: python

I can see some Python code below, but I don't know what's the purpose/use of it? Any reply will be appreciated!

```
r = []
r[:] = [r, r, None]
>>> r
>>> [[...], [...], None]
```

Comment: We cannot help you without the context of this code. Where does it come from?

Comment: As you show it to us, it doesn't make much sense. Context and use-cases are important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> r = []
> ```

This is easy.  Set `r` to be a new empty list.

> ```
> r[:] = [r, r, None]
> ```

`[r, r, None]` is a list that contains two references to the list referenced by `r`, and a `None` value.

`r[:] =` replaces all the elements of the existing list that is referred to by `r`, with the right hand side of the assignment.

The result is that `r` refers to a list that contains references to itself.

> ```
> >>> r
> >>> [[...], [...], None]
> ```

The `...` notation means that Python has spotted an infinite loop, and rather than go down the rat-hole, it just prints `...`.

The *purpose* of this code is not clear - my initial reaction is "an entry to the International Obfuscated Python Contest perhaps?"

Comment: I investigated the code further, It seems it implemented Doubly Circular linked list. r[:] = [r, r, None] is just a initialization, then it made the list like   [here](http://www.equestionanswers.com/c/c-doubly-circular-linked-list.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> r = []
>>> r[:] = [r, r, None] # You do this
```

You are assigning r to r, kind of circular link

Try accessing 0th index and you will see this

```
>>> r[0]
[[...], [...], None]
>>> r[0][0]
[[...], [...], None]
>>> r[0][0][0]
[[...], [...], None]
```

Proof: try printing IDs of r and r[0] and sooo on

```
>>> id(r[0][0][0])
4508668632
>>> id(r[0][0][0][0])
4508668632
>>> id(r[0][0][0][0][0])
4508668632
```

Comment: I also think that printing `id(r)`, `id(r[0])`, and `id(r[1])` would be more informative.