# What is the role of [:] in overwriting a list in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I came across a weird syntactical approach at work today that I couldn't wrap my head around. Let's say I have the following list:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

My objective is to filter each nested list according to some criteria and overwrite the elements of the list in place. So, let's say I want to remove odd numbers from each nested list such that `my_list` contains lists of even numbers, where the end result would look like this:

```
[[2], [4, 6]]
```

If I try to do this using a simple assignment operator, it doesn't work.

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for l in my_list:
    l = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
print(my_list)

Output: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

However, if I "slice" the list, it provides the expected output.

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for l in my_list:
    l[:] = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
print(my_list)

Output: [[2], [4, 6]]
```

My original hypothesis was that `l` was a newly created object that didn't actually point to the corresponding object in the list, but comparing the outputs of `id(x[i])`, `id(l)`, and `id(l[:])` (where `i` is the index of `l` in `x`), I realized that `l[:]` was the one with the differing id. So, if Python is creating a new object when I assign to `l[:]` then how does Python know to overwrite the existing object of `l`? Why does this work? And why doesn't the simple assignment operator `l = ...` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between slice assignment that slices the whole list and direct assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155951/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-assignment-that-slices-the-whole-list-and-d)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's subtle.

Snippet one:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    for l in my_list:
        l = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
```

Why doesn't this work? Because when you do `l =` , you're only reassigning the variable `l`, not making any change to its value.

If we write the loop out "manually", it hopefully will become more clear why this strategy fails:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

# iteration 1
l = my_list[0]
l = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]

# iteration 2
l = my_list[1]
l = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
```

Snippet two:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for l in my_list:
    l[:] = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
```

Why does this work? Because by using `l[:] =` , you're actually modifying the *value* that `l` references, not just the variable `l`. Let me elaborate.

Generally speaking, using `[:]` notation (slice notation) on lists allows one to work with a section of the list.

The simplest use is for getting values out of a list; we can write `a[n:k]` to get the `n`th, item `n+1`st item, etc, up to `k-1`. For instance:

```
>>> a = ["a", "very", "fancy", "list"]
>>> print(a[1:3])
['very', 'fancy']
```

Python also allows use of slice notation on the left-side of a `=`. In this case, it interprets the notation to mean that we want to *update* only part of a list. For instance, we can replace `"very", "fancy"` with `"not", "so", "fancy"` like so:

```
>>> print(a)
['a', 'very', 'fancy', 'list']
>>> a[1:3] = ["not", "so", "fancy"]
>>> print(a)
['a', 'not', 'so', 'fancy', 'list']
```

When using slice syntax, Python also provides some convenient shorthand. Instead of writing `[n:k]`, we can omit `n` or `k` or both.

If we omit `n`, then our slice looks like `[:k]`, and Python understands it to mean "up to `k`", i.e., the same as `[0:k]`.

If we omit `k`, then our slice looks like `a[n:]`, and Python understands it to mean "`n` and after", i.e., the same as `a[n:len(a)]`.

If we omit *both*, then both rules take place, so `a[:]` is the same as `a[0:len(a)]`, which is a slice over the entire list.

Examples:

```
>>> print(a)
['a', 'not', 'so', 'fancy', 'list']
>>> print(a[2:4])
['so', 'fancy']
>>> print(a[:4])
['a', 'not', 'so', 'fancy']
>>> print(a[2:])
['so', 'fancy', 'list']
>>> print(a[:])
['a', 'not', 'so', 'fancy', 'list']
```

Crucially, this all still applies if we are using our slice on the left-hand side of a `=`:

```
>>> print(a)
['a', 'not', 'so', 'fancy', 'list']
>>> a[:4] = ["the", "fanciest"]
>>> print(a)
['the', 'fanciest', 'list']
```

And using `[:]` means to replace every item in the list:

```
>>> print(a)
['the', 'fanciest', 'list']
>>> a[:] = ["something", "completely", "different"]
>>> print(a)
['something', 'completely', 'different']
```

Okay, so far so good.

They key thing to note is that using slice notation on the left-hand side of a list updates the list *in-place*. In other words, when I do `a[1:3] =`, the variable `a` is never updated; the list that it references is.

We can see this with `id()`, as you were doing:

```
>>> print(a)
['something', 'completely', 'different']
>>> print(id(a))
139848671387072
>>> a[1:] = ["truly", "amazing"]
>>> print(a)
['something', 'truly', 'amazing']
>>> print(id(a))
139848671387072
```

Perhaps more pertinently, this means that if `a` were a reference to a list within some other object, then using `a[:] =` will update the list *within* that object. Like so:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
>>> second_list = list_of_lists[1]
>>> print(second_list)
[3, 4]
>>> second_list[1:] = [2, 1, 'boom!']
>>> print(second_list)
[3, 2, 1, 'boom!']
>>> print(list_of_lists)
[[1, 2], [3, 2, 1, 'boom!'], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: That is perfectly explained. Thank you!